# Python 3.2.1: Can't Index Shape, Need to Access a Particular Rectangle Later

Tags: python, graphics, indexing

I am using a nested `for` loop to draw a grid of 10 rows of rectangles and 10 columns of rectangles (100 total):

```
gridTiles = []

for r in range(totalSpaces):
    for c in range(totalSpaces):
        tiles = Rectangle(Point(borderSet + r * spaceSize, borderSet + c * spaceSize), Point(borderSet + (r + 1) * spaceSize, borderSet + (c + 1) * spaceSize))
        tiles.setWidth(2)
        tiles.draw(board)
        gridTiles.append(tiles)
```

I know that the `Rectangle` does not support indexing (as shown in the TypeError I get), but I need to be able to access one specific rectangle later in my code.

Is there a way to somehow index each rectangle, so I can do something along the lines of gridTiles[3][7] later (although, of course, the way it is now, it will not allow that)? And, incidentally, I currently do not know the things that are like `__something__`, so I can't easily use any method that's done like that.

Comment: Nothing you have in that code should give you an IndexError. Please show the code and exact error which gave you a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `gridTiles` have nested lists:

```
gridTiles = []

for r in range(totalSpaces):
    row = []

    for c in range(totalSpaces):
        tiles = Rectangle(Point(borderSet + r * spaceSize, borderSet + c * spaceSize), Point(borderSet + (r + 1) * spaceSize, borderSet + (c + 1) * spaceSize))
        tiles.setWidth(2)
        tiles.draw(board)

        row.append(tiles)
    gridTiles.append(row)
```

Now you should be able to index like you want:

```
gridTiles[0][0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your method for indexing works perfectly. This has been making my head going in circles for a good part of the day.